# sql to select the the results of an update on a left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, left-join

I have two geospatial databases that I want to combine. One has region IDs and areas, the other has region IDs and lat/long data. The records in the area table are a subset of the records in the lat/long table.

I can do a left join to combine the areas and lat/long values. I then want to do an update to replace all the NULL areas with 0 and retrieve the resulting table.

The closest I got is:

```
with cte as
(select IDa, Lat, Lon, Area
from regionLL left join regionA on IDll=IDa)
update cte
set Area=0
where Area is NULL;
```

But the only thing displayed is "(0 row(s) affected)". I'm using sql server 2008.

Thank you for your help!

(edit 1: forgot a closing parenthesis. edit 2: fixed "ID" to "IDa")

Comment: Which table is `Area` in?

Comment: @Andomar The tables are `regionLL(IDll, Lat, Lon)` and `regionA(IDa, Area)`

Comment: Would you like to update areas if there is no matching lat/long record?  Would you like to alter values in the table or just select `0` if the corresponding area is `null` ?

Comment: I don't want to change the original tables at all. If region 123 has a lat/lon but no area then I want the resulting output to say "123,18.2,-66.5,0", but if 456 does have an area, I want it to be "456,19.3, -67.2,8".

Comment: In that case, avoid `update`, since that will change the original tables.  I think user3410918 has a good answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT ID
    , Lat
    , Lon
    , ISNULL(Area,0)
FROM regionLL
LEFT JOIN regionA
    ON IDll = IDa
```

Comment: This also just reports "(0 row(s) affected)"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
update a
set a.Area = 0
from regionA
inner join
(
    select ID, Lat, Lon, Area
    from regionLL 
    left join regionA on IDll=IDa
) t on (a.ID = t.ID)
where t.Area is null
```

Comment: This just reports (0 row(s) affected).